# Integrate rave flutterwave api in php

Tags: php, api, payment-gateway, flutterwave

hello I am using core PHP in client Project, I need to integrate rave flutter wave API, I have searched a lot of links
now I am checking this URL [here](https://rave-doc.herokuapp.com/)  but not getting a good result,
so please help me in rave flutter wave "Nigeria payment gateway" API in PHP

Comment: What exactly have you done? Where exactly are you facing challenges? Have you written a payment gateway before?

Comment: @rakesh_sharma https://github.com/Flutterwave/flutterwave-php

Comment: yes i have used this api but Card::charge can't return any value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our Product for collections is called Rave, please follow the steps below to get started:

1. Sign up https://ravepay.co/ , for a sanbox account sign up on http://rave.frontendpwc.com
2. Add a settlement account on sign up
3. Select a settlement preference by navigating to Account settings > Settlement preference (Find documentation attached for more detailed instruction).
4. Documentation for developers: https://flutterwavedevelopers.readme.io/v1.0

```
Pay Now
```

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function() {
     
    var chargeResponse = "",
        trxref = "FDKHGK" + Math.random(),// add your transaction ref here
        pubkey = "XXXX"; // Add public keys generated on your dashboard here
      getpaidSetup({
        customer_email: "xxxxx",// 
        amount: 1000,
        currency: "NGN",
        country: "NG",
        custom_logo: "http://imgur.com/uuRnkV9",
        custom_description:"",
        custom_title: "The Start",
        txref: trxref,
        PBFPubKey: pubkey,
        onclose: function(response) {},
        callback: function(response) {
          //flw_ref = response.tx.flwRef;
          console.log("This is the response returned after a charge", response);
          if(response.tx.chargeResponse =='00' || response.tx.chargeResponse == '0') {
            // redirect to a success page
          } else {
            // redirect to a failure page.
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

If you have any issues at any point, please let us know and we will help sort you out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are here in 2020, the docs for the payment gateway has been updated, you can check how to integrate this with laravel seamlessly using this link
https://questionbump.com/question/how-can-i-setup-flutterwave-payment-webhook-successfully-on-laravel-5/
I hope it helps someone. I struggled to get this working.